# Can I have an table index that uses the current date as a condition?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, unique-index

As an example, let us say I have a table `Coupons` that has a the fields `code`, `expiration_date`, and `status`. A coupon instance can be archived based off its `status` or `expiration_date`. If it's `status` == "archived" OR if the current date is past the coupon's `expiration_date`. I want to create a unique index for the `Coupons` table where no two "active" coupons can have the same code. So in the migration file I would want to write something like this:

```
    add_index :coupons, %i[code], where: ('status <> 2 AND (expiration_date IS NULL OR expiration_date <= ?)', Time.now.utc), unique: true, name: 'index_unique_coupon_code'
```

I can not find the proper way to write this `where` condition to use the current date when validating for uniqueness in this example.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Assuming MySQL, the first thing I would try is this:
`add_index(:coupons, %i[code], where: ('status <> 2 AND (expiration_date IS NULL OR expiration_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'), unique: true, name: 'index_unique_coupon_code')`
No guarantees though.